# Get values from object if the name of the object is stored as a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON object return with the following format:

```
"miscObject": {
    "205": [
        {
            "h": "Foo",
            "l": "Bar"
        }
        ]
    }
```

miscObject contains somewhere over 1500 entries, each named incrementally.

How can I get to the values of 'miscObject.205.h' and 'miscObject.205.l' if I have "205" stored in  variable without having to loop through all of the objects inside miscObject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>It seems that you're talking about Javascript objects rather than a JSON string.</sup>

`x[y]` and `x.y` are mostly interchangeable when accessing properties of Javascript objects, with the distinction that `y` in the former may be an *expression*.

Take advantage of this to solve your problem, like so:

```
var num = '205';
console.log(miscObject[num].l);
//                    ^^^^^
//                      \
//                     instead of `.num`, which wouldn't be the same as
//                       `num` is not the literal name of the property
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the member lookup syntax

```
var miscObject = $.parseJSON(theJsonString);
var name = '205';
miscObject[name].h;
```

Answer (score 0):

Object values can be accessed 2 ways--using the 'dot' notation as you mentioned, or by using `[]`'s:

The following should work:

```
var result = miscObject["205"].h;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var miscObject = JSON.parse(your-JSON-object);    
var value = miscObject['205'].h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the object:

```
num = '205'
miscObject[num]
```